# EMACS find-grep command switching windows

Tags: function, emacs, grep, elisp, find-grep

I have the following in my .emacs

```
(defun find-in-workspace(term)
  (interactive "sSearchInWorkspace: \n")
  (grep-find (concat "grep -rnH --include=\*.{c,cpp,h} --include=-e '" term "' /home/workspaces/*")))
```

which is just a wrapper around grep-find so that it can search all the files in my workspace.

My problem is with the *grep* buffer.  I would like to keep my cursor in the *grep* buffer's window when I select items from it so that I can quickly browse through the code, but selecting a line will automatically moves my cursor to the other window, which adds up in keystrokes when I have a list of over 5 items. Is there anyway I can build this functionality into this function, or change a setting for grep-find? I've been searching but haven't found a solution.

Comment: What if you used `find-grep-dired` and from Dired `C-o` (this displays the file in another buffer, without moving the point to that buffer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the functions `next-error` and `previous-error`. They leave the grep buffer, but they work from anywhere, so, for example, if you bind `next-error` to a convenient a key then you can keep pressing it and it will iterate over the grep buffer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! :)
I have them binded to ctrl-tab and backtab for now.

Comment: I tried to do that early but couldn't figure that out haha, been lurking on stackoverflow for years, but never noticed the checkmark.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There might be some options of grep behavior, that you might find if you dig in the `lisp/progmodes/grep.el` from the source, but I really think it might be better and easier to have a look of [GrepPlus](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepPlus) library which bring many enhancement of emacs grep.

Otherwise you could also use `occur` and see how you could customize it. In occur, when you are in the match buffer, you can it `C-o` instead of Ret, which will show in the other buffer the match you selected, keeping your cursor in the match buffer. Difference with grep, is that it only works with opened buffer. I'm rather sure `grep+` might have the equivalent. You should have a look

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions for doing exactly what you want: `previous-error-no-select` and `next-error-no-select`.

Also, you may find useful `next-error-follow-minor-mode`.